# Where is mouse configuration file in KDE5 Debian Stretch located

Tags: configuration, debian, mouse, kde-plasma

I would like to know where is the configuration file for mouse is located in Debian Stretch which uses KDE 5+ Plasma.

In Plasma, default is "single click" for opening a file. I like to create a script to overwrite the configuration so that "double click" for opening a file becomes default.

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

/home/user/.config/dolphinrc

[KDE]
SingleClick=false

Should resolve it.